# Spring security 4.x login redirects to '.../favicon' instead of expected URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have Spring Security java configuration as

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class BlogWebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
     @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()                   
                    .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()                                       
                    .antMatchers("/detail/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/post/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout");
        }

        @Autowired
        public void registerGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
          auth
              .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin")
                .password("admin")
                .roles("USER", "ADMIN");
          }

}
```

and my login form is

```
<form name='login' action="<spring:url value='/login'/>" method='POST'>
        <input class="input-field" type='text' name='username' placeholder="admin name">
        <input class="input-field" type='password' name='password' placeholder="admin password" /><br>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />           
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
    </form>
```

LoginLogoutController is

```
@Controller
public class LoginLogoutController {
    @Autowired
    private BlogService serviceImplementation;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String adminHome() {     
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String adminLogin(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("posts", serviceImplementation.getAllPosts());
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logoutPage(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null) {
            new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
        }
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

all things work perfectly but when I hit Login button it takes me to

```
localhost:8080/app/favicon.jpg
```

and a 404/ not found error after this when I hit back button of browser I see my self as logged in the app.
How can I fix this bug so that Security not take to /favicon.jpg request any suggestions please.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make an explicit `.permitAll()` for `/favicon.*` in your security configuration if it isn't stored in `/`, `/resources/**`, `/detail/**` or `/post/**` or if you don't have a favicon at all.

The latter is, because (some) browsers try to find one and requesting it at that URL. For a more sophisticated explanation on that see http://blog.codeleak.pl/2014/02/configure-faviconico-in-spring-mvc.html